# How to set rowSums(x) to equal some number, as opposed to colSums(x)

Tags: r

I have seen functions where `colSums(x)` can be set to equal some number when creating a matrix, in R, but I am wondering how to do the same with `rowSums(x)`? Specifically, I am trying to create a data table (matrix?) with 30 rows and 4 columns, where the sum of the values in each row is less than or equal to 100.

I have used replicate with `runif`.

```
x <- replicate(4, diff(c(0, sort(runif(30)), 2)))
```

I get a matrix where the `colSums(x)` is 2, but the `rowSums(x)` is not set to equal 100.

Comment: Why not `t(replicate(30, diff(c(0, sort(runif(4)), 100))))`?

Comment: Thank you, Rui Barradas. This works! I was just wondering, though (as I am new to R): which part of the function makes it so that the values in the last column are always around 99?